# Mocking GetEnumerator using Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I'm trying to mock the [Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Variables.aspx) interface in Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word assembly

```
var variables = new Mock<Variables>();
variables.Setup(x => x.Count).Returns(2);
variables.Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(TagCollection);

private IEnumerator TagCollection()
{
    var tag1 = new Mock<Variable>();
    tag1.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("Foo");
    tag1.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns("Bar");

    var tag2 = new Mock<Variable>();
    tag2.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns("Baz");
    tag2.Setup(x => x.Value).Returns("Qux");

    yield return tag1.Object;
    yield return tag2.Object;
}
```

I have code that reads like the following:

```
// _variables is an instance of Variables interface
var tags = from variable in _variables.OfType<Variable>()
           where variable.Name == "Foo"
           select variable.Value;
var result = tags.ToList();
```

Last line in the code above throws a NullReferenceException. If I use a foreach loop to iterate through _variables collection, I could access mock objects of Variable without any problem. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does your `foreach` that works look like?

Comment: Sorry, it's abit of a wild guess, but I had a similar problem when returning iterating through collections during mocking and it was because I wasn't calling to list at the end. Try This:                                  `var tags = variables.OfType<Variable>().Where(x => x.Name == "Foo").Select(x => x.Value).ToList();`

Comment: @William The OP calls `ToList` on the next line.

Comment: @William it throws NullReferenceException

Comment: My guess would be that `OfType` isn't playing nice with the mocked objects.  Do you use `OfType` with the `foreach` that works?  Also what is the type of `_variables` that requires you to use `OfType` in the first place.

Comment: @juharr foreach (Variable variable in _variables)
{
    if (variable.Name == "Foo")
        return variable.Value;
}

Comment: @Raj Instead of `OfType` try `Cast<Variable>()` instead.  That would be the equivalent of your `foreach`.   Unless `_variables` is something like `List<Vaiables>`, in which case you shouldn't need `OfType` or `Cast`.

Comment: Extension methods like OfType<T>, Cast<T> throws an exception. Also when I try to expand Result view in debugger I get "Enumeration yielded no results"

Comment: Where's the NullReferenceException coming from? The query you wrote should never have a return value of null. You might be getting a cascading null reference exception that's actually stemming from an `InvalidOperationException` occurring because you're setting up the enumerator of the object using an iterator block, which can throw that type of exception.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
variables
    .As<IEnumerable>()
    .Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(TagCollection);
```

There are two different methods, one declared in the base interface and one declared in `Variables`.

When you `foreach` directly, the latter is called because that method ***hides*** the same-looking member from the base type. `foreach` calls the `public` method when one exists, and in that case `IEnumerable` does not matter.

When you call the `.OfType<Variable>()` Linq extension, the reference is cast to `IEnumerable` interface, and the name hiding is no longer present. The method on the base interface is called.

It is like the difference between:

```
_variables.GetEnumerator();
```

and:

```
((IEnumerable)_variables).GetEnumerator();
```

You can think of the mock Moq generates as this:

```
public class TheTypeMoqMakes : Variables 
{
  Enumerator Variables.GetEnumerator()
  {
    // Use return value from after
    // expression tree you provided with 'Setup' without 'As'.
    // If you did not provide one, just return null.
  }

  Enumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    // Use return value from after
    // expression tree you provided with 'Setup' with 'As<IEnumerable>'.
    // If you did not provide one, just return null.
  }

  // other methods and properties
}
```

The reason why Moq returns null in case the member was not `Setup`, is that you have `MockBehavior.Loose`. Always consider `MockBehavior.Strict` instead.

---

I cannot understand why the authors of `Variables` interface [chose to use method hiding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.variables_methods.aspx) in this case.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. As<T> setup was completely new to me.